# How to validate no duplicate entries in YAML on Play?

Tags: java, playframework, yaml

This has happened to me a few times before: By too much copy-pasting, I defined multiple entities in my Play YAML file that have the same ID.

This does not yield a good error ("duplicate entity defined in YAML: 'foo'), but rather makes the YAML parsing "behave strangely" for me. I believe in other cases it would just silently drop the duplicate entities.

What's a good way to validate the YAML file does not have duplicates, and produce a clear error if it does?

Comment: I've also seen issues with dates not being parsed correctly without errors or warnings logged...

Answer (score 1):

If it's OK to use an external tool, a linter can validate that your YAML file does not have duplicates. For instance, you could use the [yamllint](http://yamllint.readthedocs.org/) command:

```
sudo pip install yamllint
```

Specifically, it has a rule `key-duplicates` that detects repeated entries:

```
$ cat test.yml
foo: bar
foo: baz

$ yamllint test.yml
test.yml
  2:1       error    duplication of key "foo" in mapping  (key-duplicates)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using constraints on your entities? Unique checks?

Comment: I'm referring to the "YAML ID" that each entity gets - this string is not reflected in the model in any way, it's just used to refer to other YAML entities. It doesn't exist in the model itself.

Comment: Still, if you duplicate lines, you will have duplicate data for some fields. You should check on those fields.

Comment: What I currently have is an error loading the YAML file, but the error really does not explain the problem. I would like to run a validation step before loading the YAML.